# How to query product name with begin_with(like) condition in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local

I have product table ,where product code is partition key ,'meta' is short key ,product name and other some attributes are non key attributes.
I tried put product name as short key ,but i have to delete old entry and need to insert new entry whenever product name getting updated.So i avoided product name as a partition/short key.

Now i have access pattern to get product details based on product name which is not fully given by user , user will provide first three character and database will send all items based first three characters .But i not able to achieve this without scan.

I don't want to do scan operation as it is inefficient query and more cost.

I cannot create Global index also , because when i query items i need to provide product id (Partition key) and product name with begin_with condition . if i know product key then directly i can get product details without product name.

Please some one help me to overcome this issue .

Answer (score 0):

To make the items **efficiently** searchable by the first three characters of the product name, you can use GSI, but you'll need to do some additional preperations:

GSI can only index an entire attribute, not the first three characters of one. So you can add another column, with the first three characters of the product name. In this example, every time your application creates or updates product_name with "somename", it will also update product_name_beginning to "som" (the first three letters). Then, you add a GSI on this new attribute "product_name_beginning", and do queries based on this new attribute.

Note that if you have already-existing data, this solution requires that you add the new attribute to the existing items, otherwise they will be missing in the new index.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. It is really useful.